# Insert datastage type timestamp in table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp, datastage

I have a datastage project, in which, from oracle tables, I write on SQL Server tables.
The server is on unix machine.

The insert statement, via odbc stage, doesn't work.

Among the fields target to load, there are SQL Server datetime and timestamp.
I do not know how to convert timestamp datastage in those two formats.

Please, can someone help me!?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Datastage "timestamp" is datetime in SQL Server.

SQL Server timestamp is now "rowversion" and is a binary values for the, er, row version

Comment: So, Can I map datastage timestamp to sqlserver datetime!? How Can I convert datastage timestamp to sqlserver timestamp, before load data!?

Comment: Mapping from timestamp datastage to datetime sqlserver is ok,
but can I map timestamp datastage to timestamp sqlserver!?
Thank you

Comment: @sangi: no. timestamp in SQL Server is not a "timestamp" like I said; it's a vesion number for a row and has no link at all to dates and times. It's badly named...